# usando django, y al convertir un dataframe a json usando to_json, la respuesta en html aparece como ' " ' y con '\', como lo puedo corregir

Tags: html, python, django, response

```py
libro_actualizado=pd.concat([datos_viejos,df])
libr_dicc = libro_actualizado.to_json(orient='columns')


"{\"nombre_ter\":{\"0\":\"JAVIER HERNANDEZ\",\"1\":\"BERMUDEZ CARLOS\",\"2\"....
```

Comment: con print(libr_dicc) en python aparece normal sin comillas ni la diagonal

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour].Me parece que la explicación que das (solo en el título) no deja ver claramente como se da el problema que tienes. Creo que falta explicar o mostrar, por ejemplo, cómo el contenido de la variable `libr_dicc` llega a HTML. Para más información lee [ask].